# REST WCF 4 Service with Custom Basic Authentication over SSL in IIS

Tags: wcf, iis, rest, ssl

I'm looking for a complete step-by-step guide or a sample project about implementing a RESTful Service using .NET 4.0 using Custom Basic Authentication over HTTPS hosted in IIS.

I've been googling about it for 3 days and I could only find either an implementation with WCF 3.5 which is very different, or without Custom Basic Authentication, or without SSL.

Basically I implemented my REST service on WCF 4, and added SSL, but I can't use a custom authentication using my custom users database.

Any references would be really appreciated.

Comment: What is different with the 3.5 implementation you found? Any reason why it won't work in 4.0?

Comment: There is an example here (instructions are very detailed and sources are included):
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/379636/WCF-Basic-Authentication-with-SQL-Membership-Provi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible with custom [HTTP module](http://custombasicauth.codeplex.com/) allowing basic authentication against custom credential store. Built-in module in IIS supports only windows accounts.

Answer (score 1):

It's not currently possible using the available WCF extension points.

Answer (score 0):

I wrestled with this for a while and ended up just implementing basic auth in my service. Check WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.Headers for an 'Authorization' header. If it's missing or the credentials don't match set the challenge header and return a 401 status:

```
WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm=\"myrealm\""); 
throw new WebFaultException<string>("Username and password needed", HttpStatus.Unauthorized);
```

That's enough to trigger a browser to prompt the user for credentials. See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617 for more on basic auth, http://ithoughthecamewithyou.com/post/Basic-HTTP-auth-for-an-IIS-hosted-WCF-4-RESTful-service.aspx for more on this frustrating missing capability.

Comment: BTW... I think your last paramter should read `HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized`